# Remove Preview window for all Finder windows

Tags: macos, finder

One day something happened and the Preview window on the right hand side of the window started appearing in all my Finder windows. How can I make it go away permanently? If I close it, it only closes for that one particular folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all Finder windows except for one.
2. In the only open Finder window, arrange it in a manner that you'd
   like as the default without having the Preview window showing.
3. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> (⌘J) and then at the bottom of the
   View Options sheet, click the <kbd>Use as Defaults</kbd> button.